# ftp_connect not working even with localhost

Tags: php, ftp

I have this sample script I'm trying to get working and for some reason is not. I've tried remote and locahost server and it always die.

I installed ftp client on the server in which this runs from (I used lftp) and I'm able to connect just fine. The remote server is accepting connections and I can connect from other places just fine.

The server I run this PHP from is a CentOS 7

```
<?php

// $ftp_server="remoteftpserver.com";
 $ftp_server="localhost";
 $ftp_user_name="username";
 $ftp_user_pass="pass";
 $file = "test.txt";
 $remote_file = "test.txt";

 // set up basic connection
 $conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Unable to connect to server $ftp_server");
var_dump($conn_id);
 // login with username and password
 $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// close the connection
 ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Any ideas what may be wrong? It is strange that I can connect through command line but not using PHP, would it be a configuration on the php.ini I need to check?

In my PHPinfo page I can see:

```
FTP support enabled
FTPS support    enabled
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I just found where the problem was.. It turned to be this:

Issue was SELinux. I didn't want to turn it off so I checked the status of `httpd_can_network_connect` by running `getsebool httpd_can_network_connect` and noticed it was off so I turned it on by doing this:

```
setsebool httpd_can_network_connect=1
```

To enable after reboot, do this:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1
```